# How to align button in the header to the right side of header in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, button, icons, ionic4, toolbar

Button is aligned right in the toolbar but the icon is not shown.

Only white box appear.

**.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title style="text-align: center;">RE-MED+</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons slot="primary">
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="exit"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

It looks like this.

[image]

I want Like this

[image]

Comment: Add the component of menu button, your question given is not  lear or enough to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your `.html`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="dark">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title class="ion-text-center">RE-MED+</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button fill="clear">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="exit"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work in Ionic5. Maybe Ionic4...?

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Hello World</ion-title> 
      <ion-button slot="end" (click)="actionbutton()">Close</ion-button>  
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved.

I have created CSS for another component.

I don't know how but it applies to ion-button so I change the name of that CSS.

Its name was `.button` I changed to `.button_border`

**.css**

```
.button_border{
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: white;
    color: #0032fe;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 34px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```